# View redrawn in the wrong position after closing the keyboard - Cordova/PhoneGap - Android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, view, keyboard

I have a Cordova application (using the angularjs framework), here is my view:

[image]

When I focus an input that that requires the view to move up to keep the input visible when the (onscreen) keyboard is showing like so:

[image]

When I change the focus from the input to elsewhere (blur), the keyboard closes (like it should) but redraws the view in the wrong position:

[image]

When I inspect with Chrome, it shows all the elements in the position they should be and not where they are on the display:

[image]

I have absolutely no idea what is causing this bug, I have tried redrawing the view in the `onDraw` method, thus infinitely redrawing the view to see if that would fix it but to no avail. Any ideas?

**Extra details**
Cordova version: `3.5.0-0.2.4`
Device: `Nexus 10 - Android 4.4.4`

Answer (score 1):

I have found a fix/hack, not a great one however it's better than nothing.

By hiding the `html` tag and then re-displaying it redraws the view correctly.

```
 fixAndroidKitkatDisplayBug: function () {
        $(document).on('blur', 'input', function () {
            var htmlTags = document.getElementsByTagName('html');
            var html = htmlTags[0];
            html.style.display = 'none';
            html.offsetHeight; // no need to store this anywhere, the reference is enough
            html.style.display = 'block';
        });
    }
```

Then in the index.js, after the "onDeviceReady" I call this method like so

```
setTimeout(function (){
    if (typeof(device) != 'undefined' && device.platform && device.platform == "Android" && device.version && parseFloat(device.version) == 4.4) {
       fixAndroidKitkatDisplayBug();
    }
}, 100);
```

(For me I needed the setTimeout in order for device to be defined)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem on our app by adding the following 'hack' to my submit button code.

```
$('html, body').scrollTop(0);
$('#usernamefield').blur();
$('#passwordfield').blur();
$('#loginform_submit').blur();
```

So I forced the html and body elements to scroll to the very top and also made sure no element had focus so the softkeyboard would actually disappear before moving on.

Hope this helps you as well.

/Mika

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. But i solve using this jQuery code.

```
$('input').on('blur',function(){
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
})
```

It's worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I faced an identical issue with Sencha Touch on Android 4.4.2, and finally this made it work:

```
if (Ext.os.is('Android')) {
window.repaint = {};
//dirty fix for screen is scrolling down when user hides keyboard
window.onresize = function() {
    var repaintFn = function() {
        Ext.defer(function() {
            var body = document.body;
            window.repaint.isRepainting = false;
            if (window.repaint.counter < 3) {
                window.repaint.counter++;
                body.style.overflow = (body.style.overflow == 'hidden') ? 'auto' : 'hidden';
                repaintFn.call(this);
            }
        }, 1500, this);
    };
    if (!window.repaint.isRepainting) {
        repaintFn.call(this);
        window.repaint = {
            counter: 0,
            isRepainting: true
        };
    }
};
```

}

The line that does the trick is:

```
body.style.overflow = (body.style.overflow == 'hidden') ? 'auto' : 'hidden';
```

Rest of the code is to call the same function 4 times at a delay, to ensure it works even on low performance devices, where there might be a lag between the firing of resize event and the screen actually shifting down.